# Adding a block through layout to other pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

The block in our created extension doesn't appear any content.

The content we are about to add is a banner extension that can be turn on and off in the Admin. We then add the banner block code anywhere it's required in xml files.

> app/code/local/Company/SocialRating/etc/config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_SocialRating>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_SocialRating>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <rating>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_SocialRating</module>
                    <frontName>social-rating</frontName>
                </args>
            </rating>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <socialRating>
                    <file>social-rating.xml</file>
                </socialRating>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <socialRating>
                <class>Company_SocialRating_Block_Banner</class>
            </socialRating>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Company/SocialRating/Block/Banner.php

```php
class Company_SocialRating_Block_Banner extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

> app/design/frontend/superb/desktop/layout/social-rating.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>superb/ratings-and-review.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

> app/design/frontend/superb/desktop/template/social-rating/banner.phtml

```html
<h1>test content</h1>
```

Then we thought we add it to the checkout success page like below

> app/design/frontend/superb/desktop/layout/checkout.xml

```xml
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="socialRating/banner" name="social.rating.banner" template="social-rating/banner.phtml" />
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

After added it to the checkout success page it doesn't appear.
Cache has been flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files are ok, except the layout. It doesn't show anywhere because "checkout.xml" is not declared anywhere.
Instead of declaring another .xml layout file, you can put the code in your "social-rating.xml".

put this code in the `<layout></layout>`tag:

```
    <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="socialRating/banner" name="social.rating.banner" template="social-rating/banner.phtml" />
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

in `<checkout_onepage_success>` you can remove the `<block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>` because is already declared in another magento's layout file, if you dont you will see it displayed twice.

For your main problem, the block not loading, there is an error in your config.xml when you declare your block you dont have to tell magento what name the block has:

```
    <global>
      <blocks>
         <socialrating>
            <class>Company_Socialrating_Block</class>
         </socialrating>
      </blocks>
    </global>
```

If the problem is your Block, or you think so, you can replace the  in your layout with the `core/template` block, so you are sure that this block is correctly declared for this purpose.

Last thing, use a simply nomenclature for your modules, because SocialRating can cause some conflicts, just rename it Socialrating and it is all good (this is my personal advice, less chaotic).